# Ultrasonic sensor code

Tags: sensor

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
trig=7
echo=11
t=time.time()
GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.IN)
While (t+3)>time.time():
    start=0
    end=0
    GPIO.output(trig,True)


    time.sleep(0.000001)

    GPIO.output(trig,False)

    while GPIO.input(echo)==False:
        start=time.time()

    while GPIO.input(echo)==True:
        end=time.time()

    sig_time = end-start

    dist = sig_time * 17000


    print("dist: ",dist)

    time.sleep(0.5)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Ultrasonic sensor. It works when while t+3 code is not included.but when it is it dosnt why. it just run but no output. After if i run it again it give runtime warning gpio already in use why? Plz give me suitable code to run it for 3s giving all distances

Comment: This appears to be a general Python question, the Pi is irrelevant.

Comment: `While` is not valid Python

Comment: @Thomas Weller plz elaborate

Comment: `While` with a captial W is not valid Python. It must be `while`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer (a little bit)
When we set

```
while (t+3) >float(time.time()):
```

It works